# Load model to array in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-models

If I save an array using `@levels.each(&:save)` how do i load it back from the model Level?
That is: what is the appropriate command to repopulate the array from the saved data

```
@levels = Level.find_all
```

Does not seem to exist, I am pretty new to this as you see, i want to store and load, levels!

Here's my GamesController:

```
def initialize
@levels = [] unless @levels
@levels = levels
```

end

```
def add_level
  levels << Level.new
  levels.each(&:save)
  redirect_to edit_game_path(params[:id])
end
```

and the model:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :levels
end
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. You already have levels in `@levels`, why do you need to load them again?

Comment: I want to have a list of the levels belonging to the game on loading the page, so i guessed i had to load from the levels to some @levels list in the game controller everytime the page reloads...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your association is :

Game has many levels and level belongs to a game.

Then, 
@game = Game.find_by_id(params[:id])  #whoesoever game page is it
@levels = @game.present? ? @game.levels : []

I hope, i understood your problem

Comment: I have @game = Game.find(params[:id])
But how do I connect levels to this game and how do i store/save levels in a game?

Comment: @game.levels just gives "undefined method `levels' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: You should make a belongs_to association in level.rb model.

For this, write the below line in level.rb file.
belongs_to :game


and you should have game_id column in levels table.

Also, if you are getting undefined method 'levels' for nil class.. Then do verify if you are receiving params[:id] or not.

Then @game.levels will work.

Answer (score 1):

```
@levels = Level.all
```

Should give you an array of level objects. Declaring this instance variable in your GamesController will make it accessible to your view.

Comment: Almost right, it gets all the levels but the levels are supposed to belong to a certain game. For instance game1->level1,level2 whilst game2->levelx,levely